# Issue when starting Apache Servicemix after first install

Tags: installation, apache-servicemix

I am new to apache camel and servicemix. I have downloaded apache serviceMix (zip) on my windows, but running servicemix.bat returns an error on my cmd. Error:

```
Could not create framework: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(ArrayList.java:371)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:384)
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.getCurrentModule(BundleImpl.java:1050)
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.getSymbolicName(BundleImpl.java:859)
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.toString(Felix.java:1019)
at org.apache.felix.framework.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:128)
at org.apache.felix.framework.Logger._log(Logger.java:181)
at org.apache.felix.framework.Logger.log(Logger.java:114)
at org.apache.felix.framework.ExtensionManager.<init>(ExtensionManager.java:201)
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.<init>(Felix.java:374)
at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkFactory.newFramework(FrameworkFactory.java:28)
at org.apache.karaf.main.Main.launch(Main.java:266)
at org.apache.karaf.main.Main.main(Main.java:427)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

There is a known issue in ServiceMix <= 4.4.2 with Java 7.
You have to switch back to Java 6.

Comment: This is not an issue. SMX 4.4.x does NOT support Java 7. ServiceMix 4.5 supports Java 7.

Answer (score 0):

The error can be resolved by installing 1.6 java, servicemix 4.4 support 1.6 java.